# Add row unique inside of group

Tags: postgresql

I have schema
`id | company_id | tag`

So I trying to add new unique tag for every `company_id`.
What would be the best way to achieve it? Select by `company_id` first and refuse to add tag? Or postgres is able to do it in one shot?

So if I try to add tag `tag1` - nothing would happen

```
id | company_id | tag
1  | 1          | tag1
2  | 1          | tag2
3  | 1          | tag3
```

Comment: Please show as a sample of your expected result.

Comment: Is the problem: "Generating a unique tag value per company" or is the problem "how do I check if the new tag still exist" (the constraint)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `UNIQUE` constraint to column `tag` and Postgres will do it (refuse duplicates) for you .

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT tag_un UNIQUE (tag);
```

This makes `tag` unique across the table. If you need that `tag` be unique per `company_id` then

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT tag_company_un UNIQUE (tag, company_id);
```

Comment: In this case tag would be unique across the table, not across company, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but you can also restrict duplicates per company. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c0b7bb9bd58b8f47ece40f926de24ad)

You can create an `UNIQUE` constraint using both columns. So the combination of both would be unique. Using the same `tag` on another `company_id` would be ok:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT tag_unique UNIQUE (company_id, tag);
```